# Android Studio SQLite database asset into Recyclerview but only showing specific data

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I'm new to Android Studio having only worked with it for two months and been coding with Java for a year.

Currently I'm working on a pet adoption application where the goal is to have the user answer four questions about the kind of pet they want and based on the checkboxes the application will show a list of pets that match the user's wants.

I thought I could use SQLite as the database to add the pets in and then when the user checks the checkbox and submits the application can review the database and send the pet's name, age, and gender in a Recyclerview.

I'm finding out it is not as easy as I thought and can use some outside suggestions as I only have two more weeks to work on it. Here is what I have so far:

[Main Activity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ImSlW.jpg)

**DataBaseHelper**

```
import android.content.Context;
import com.readystatesoftware.sqliteasset.SQLiteAssetHelper;

public class DBHelper extends SQLiteAssetHelper {

    public static final String DBNAME = "PetAdoption.db";
    public static final int DBVERSION = 1;

    public DBHelper(Context context) {

        super(context,DBNAME,null,DBVERSION);
    }
}
```

**DatabaseAccess**

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

public class DatabaseAccess {

    private SQLiteOpenHelper openHelper;
    private SQLiteDatabase database;
    private static DatabaseAccess instance;

    /**
     * Private constructor to avoid object creation from outside classes.
     *
     * @param context
     */
    private DatabaseAccess(Context context) {
        this.openHelper = new DBHelper(context);
    }

    /**
     * Return a singleton instance of DatabaseAccess.
     *
     * @param context the Context
     * @return the instance of DatabaseAccess
     */
    public static DatabaseAccess getInstance(Context context) {
        if (instance == null) {
            instance = new DatabaseAccess(context);
        }
        return instance;
    }

    /**
     * Open the database connection.
     */
    public void openDatabase() {

        this.database = openHelper.getWritableDatabase();


    }

    public SQLiteDatabase getWritableDatabase() {

        return openHelper.getWritableDatabase();

    }

    public SQLiteDatabase getReadableDataBase() {
        return openHelper.getReadableDatabase();
    }


    /**
     * Close the database connection.
     */
    public void closeDatabase() {
        if (database != null) {
            this.database.close();
        }
    }
}
```

**Main Activity**

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Context context;
    private String query;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        DatabaseAccess databaseAccess = DatabaseAccess.getInstance(context);
        databaseAccess.openDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = databaseAccess.getWritableDatabase().rawQuery(query, null);

    }
}
```

I know I still need a model for the Recylerview and specific code to pull the pets that match the checkboxes, but I'm not sure I'm even going in the right direction. Any suggestions would be very helpful.

Comment: I suggest you learn to use Room(https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/) as soon as possible. It's much easier than working with sqlite directly. 1st, plan out how everything is going to work. 2nd, build your database connections. 3rd, start adding crud operations. Create an operation, test with dummy data, and repeat until you've got a stable flow. Lastly, replace dummy data with real data and you're done

Answer (score 0):

> Any suggestions would be very helpful.

***Perhaps consider the following.***

First rather than have an asset (pre-packaged database) the demo creates the database and loads some data (for convenience).

As the schama isn't available this has been made up (this answer is about the principle as opposed to the actual data which is not available).

The table is called **pet** it has 5 columns:-

- **_id** (the android standard for the id column that uniquely identifies a row)
- **type** for the type of pet (dog, cat ....)
- **breed** e.g. alsatian
- **lifestage** newborn, old ....
- **cost**

Some data is loaded (in the onCreate method, ***Note** instead of **SQLiteAssetHelper** the stock **SQliteOpenHelper** has been used as there is no asset to load*)

So purely for convenience DBHelper is :-

```
public class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper /* changed for simulation of asset */ {

   public static final String DBNAME = "PetAdoption.db";
   public static final int DBVERSION = 1;

   private static String[] testdata1 = new String[]{"Dog","Alsatian","old","100"};
   private static String[] testdata2 = new String[]{"Dog","Golden Retriever","newborn","200"};
   private static String[] testdata3 = new String[]{"Cat","Siamese","young","150"};
   private static String[] testdata4 = new String[]{"Cat","Burmese","mature","110"};
   private static String[] testdata5 = new String[]{"Cat","Persian","old","75"};
   private static String[] testdata6 = new String[]{"Dog","Corgi","mature","300"};

   public DBHelper(Context context) {
      super(context,DBNAME,null,DBVERSION);
   }

   /* ADDED to simulate getting data from asset */
   @Override
   public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase) {
      sqLiteDatabase.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS pet (" +
              BaseColumns._ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY" +
              "," + "type TEXT" +
              "," + "breed TEXT" +
              "," + "lifestage TEXT" +
              "," + "cost REAL" +
              ")"
      );
      insertTestData(sqLiteDatabase,testdata1);
      insertTestData(sqLiteDatabase,testdata2);
      insertTestData(sqLiteDatabase,testdata3);
      insertTestData(sqLiteDatabase,testdata4);
      insertTestData(sqLiteDatabase,testdata5);
      insertTestData(sqLiteDatabase,testdata6);

   }

   private void insertTestData(SQLiteDatabase db, String[] data) {
      if (data.length != 4) return;
      ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
      cv.put("type",data[0]);
      cv.put("breed",data[1]);
      cv.put("lifestage",data[2]);
      cv.put("cost",data[3]);
      db.insert("pet",null,cv);
   }

   @Override
   public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase, int i, int i1) {
   }
}
```

The resultant **pet** table will then be:-

[image]

To give an idea of what could be done to select data with some flexibility **MainActivity** has been changed to be:-

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    //private Context context;
    //private String query;

    private String typeSelection = "dog";
    private String breedSelection = "alsatian";
    private String lifeStageSelection = "young";
    private String lowerCostRangeSelection = "0.0";
    private String upperCostRangeSelection = "150";


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        /*
        DatabaseAccess databaseAccess = DatabaseAccess.getInstance(context);
        databaseAccess.openDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = databaseAccess.getWritableDatabase().rawQuery(query, null);
         */
        DatabaseUtils.dumpCursor(
                getSelection(typeSelection,breedSelection,lifeStageSelection,lowerCostRangeSelection,upperCostRangeSelection)
        );
        DatabaseUtils.dumpCursor(
                getSelection("Dog",null,null,null,null)
        );
        DatabaseUtils.dumpCursor(
                getSelection("Cat",null,null,null,null)
        );
        DatabaseUtils.dumpCursor(
                getSelection(null,null,null,null,null)
        );
    }


    private Cursor getSelection(String type, String breed, String lifeStage, String lowerCost, String upperCost ) {
        String[] args = null;
        ArrayList<String> argsArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
        StringBuilder whereClause = new StringBuilder();
        if (type != null && type.length() > 0) {
            if (whereClause.length() < 1) whereClause.append(" ");
            else whereClause.append(" AND ");
            whereClause.append(" type=?");
            argsArrayList.add(type);
        }
        if (breed != null && breed.length() > 0) {
            if (whereClause.length() < 1) whereClause.append(" ");
            else whereClause.append(" AND ");
            whereClause.append(" breed=?");
            argsArrayList.add(breed);
        }
        if (lifeStage != null && type.length() > 0) {
            if (whereClause.length() < 1) whereClause.append(" ");
            else whereClause.append(" AND ");
            whereClause.append(" lifestage=?");
            argsArrayList.add(lifeStage);
        }
        if (lowerCost != null && upperCost != null && lowerCost.length() > 0 && upperCost.length() > 0) {
            if (whereClause.length() < 1) whereClause.append(" ");
            else whereClause.append(" AND ");
            whereClause.append(" cost BETWEEN ? AND ?");
            argsArrayList.add(lowerCost);
            argsArrayList.add(upperCost);
        }
        if (whereClause.length() > 1) {
            args = new String[argsArrayList.size()];
            int i = 0;
            for (String s: argsArrayList) {
                args[i++] = s;
            }
        }
        return DatabaseAccess.getInstance(this).getWritableDatabase().query("pet",null,whereClause.toString(),args,null,null,null);
    }
}
```

the **getSelection** method being the main addition i.e. the code that allows selection according to, in this case, 5 values:-

- the type
- the breed
- the lifestage
- the lower cost and and the upper cost (i.e. a range selection)
- the SQLiteDatabase conveneince **query** method has been used, this is recommended over rawQuery.

The method is designed to be flexible and allow selection by none are all values. None would select every row.

- Note that lower and upper cost must both be provided as they are a range.

The code within the onCreate method simply calls the **getSelection** method to reflect various selections.

The first of the 4, will retrieve nothing as no row would match all the given criteria.
The second will select rows where **type** is **Dog** (3 rows).
The third will select rows where the **type** is **Cat** (the other 3 rows).
The fourth returns all rows (as nulls are passed which equates to no selections criteria).

- Note the method hasn't undergone comprehensive testing and is meant as a pointer.
- DatabaseUtils is a class that as it's name suggests has some useful utilities, like, as demonstrated dumping a Cursor.

The **Result** as output to the log being:-

```
2022-10-16 22:56:51.850 I/System.out: >>>>> Dumping cursor android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor@9c8df94
2022-10-16 22:56:51.850 I/System.out: <<<<<


2022-10-16 22:56:51.851 I/System.out: >>>>> Dumping cursor android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor@f1e7a3d
2022-10-16 22:56:51.852 I/System.out: 0 {
2022-10-16 22:56:51.852 I/System.out:    _id=1
2022-10-16 22:56:51.852 I/System.out:    type=Dog
2022-10-16 22:56:51.852 I/System.out:    breed=Alsatian
2022-10-16 22:56:51.853 I/System.out:    lifestage=old
2022-10-16 22:56:51.853 I/System.out:    cost=100
2022-10-16 22:56:51.853 I/System.out: }
2022-10-16 22:56:51.853 I/System.out: 1 {
2022-10-16 22:56:51.853 I/System.out:    _id=2
2022-10-16 22:56:51.853 I/System.out:    type=Dog
2022-10-16 22:56:51.853 I/System.out:    breed=Golden Retriever
2022-10-16 22:56:51.853 I/System.out:    lifestage=newborn
2022-10-16 22:56:51.853 I/System.out:    cost=200
2022-10-16 22:56:51.854 I/System.out: }
2022-10-16 22:56:51.854 I/System.out: 2 {
2022-10-16 22:56:51.854 I/System.out:    _id=6
2022-10-16 22:56:51.854 I/System.out:    type=Dog
2022-10-16 22:56:51.854 I/System.out:    breed=Corgi
2022-10-16 22:56:51.854 I/System.out:    lifestage=mature
2022-10-16 22:56:51.854 I/System.out:    cost=300
2022-10-16 22:56:51.854 I/System.out: }
2022-10-16 22:56:51.854 I/System.out: <<<<<


2022-10-16 22:56:51.854 I/System.out: >>>>> Dumping cursor android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor@166d232
2022-10-16 22:56:51.855 I/System.out: 0 {
2022-10-16 22:56:51.855 I/System.out:    _id=3
2022-10-16 22:56:51.856 I/System.out:    type=Cat
2022-10-16 22:56:51.856 I/System.out:    breed=Siamese
2022-10-16 22:56:51.856 I/System.out:    lifestage=young
2022-10-16 22:56:51.856 I/System.out:    cost=150
2022-10-16 22:56:51.856 I/System.out: }
2022-10-16 22:56:51.856 I/System.out: 1 {
2022-10-16 22:56:51.856 I/System.out:    _id=4
2022-10-16 22:56:51.856 I/System.out:    type=Cat
2022-10-16 22:56:51.856 I/System.out:    breed=Burmese
2022-10-16 22:56:51.856 I/System.out:    lifestage=mature
2022-10-16 22:56:51.856 I/System.out:    cost=110
2022-10-16 22:56:51.856 I/System.out: }
2022-10-16 22:56:51.856 I/System.out: 2 {
2022-10-16 22:56:51.856 I/System.out:    _id=5
2022-10-16 22:56:51.856 I/System.out:    type=Cat
2022-10-16 22:56:51.856 I/System.out:    breed=Persian
2022-10-16 22:56:51.856 I/System.out:    lifestage=old
2022-10-16 22:56:51.856 I/System.out:    cost=75
2022-10-16 22:56:51.856 I/System.out: }
2022-10-16 22:56:51.856 I/System.out: <<<<<


2022-10-16 22:56:51.857 I/System.out: >>>>> Dumping cursor android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor@17eeb83
2022-10-16 22:56:51.857 I/System.out: 0 {
2022-10-16 22:56:51.857 I/System.out:    _id=1
2022-10-16 22:56:51.857 I/System.out:    type=Dog
2022-10-16 22:56:51.857 I/System.out:    breed=Alsatian
2022-10-16 22:56:51.857 I/System.out:    lifestage=old
2022-10-16 22:56:51.858 I/System.out:    cost=100
2022-10-16 22:56:51.858 I/System.out: }
2022-10-16 22:56:51.858 I/System.out: 1 {
2022-10-16 22:56:51.858 I/System.out:    _id=2
2022-10-16 22:56:51.858 I/System.out:    type=Dog
2022-10-16 22:56:51.858 I/System.out:    breed=Golden Retriever
2022-10-16 22:56:51.858 I/System.out:    lifestage=newborn
2022-10-16 22:56:51.858 I/System.out:    cost=200
2022-10-16 22:56:51.858 I/System.out: }
2022-10-16 22:56:51.858 I/System.out: 2 {
2022-10-16 22:56:51.858 I/System.out:    _id=3
2022-10-16 22:56:51.858 I/System.out:    type=Cat
2022-10-16 22:56:51.858 I/System.out:    breed=Siamese
2022-10-16 22:56:51.858 I/System.out:    lifestage=young
2022-10-16 22:56:51.858 I/System.out:    cost=150
2022-10-16 22:56:51.858 I/System.out: }
2022-10-16 22:56:51.858 I/System.out: 3 {
2022-10-16 22:56:51.858 I/System.out:    _id=4
2022-10-16 22:56:51.858 I/System.out:    type=Cat
2022-10-16 22:56:51.858 I/System.out:    breed=Burmese
2022-10-16 22:56:51.858 I/System.out:    lifestage=mature
2022-10-16 22:56:51.859 I/System.out:    cost=110
2022-10-16 22:56:51.859 I/System.out: }
2022-10-16 22:56:51.859 I/System.out: 4 {
2022-10-16 22:56:51.859 I/System.out:    _id=5
2022-10-16 22:56:51.859 I/System.out:    type=Cat
2022-10-16 22:56:51.859 I/System.out:    breed=Persian
2022-10-16 22:56:51.859 I/System.out:    lifestage=old
2022-10-16 22:56:51.859 I/System.out:    cost=75
2022-10-16 22:56:51.859 I/System.out: }
2022-10-16 22:56:51.859 I/System.out: 5 {
2022-10-16 22:56:51.859 I/System.out:    _id=6
2022-10-16 22:56:51.859 I/System.out:    type=Dog
2022-10-16 22:56:51.859 I/System.out:    breed=Corgi
2022-10-16 22:56:51.859 I/System.out:    lifestage=mature
2022-10-16 22:56:51.859 I/System.out:    cost=300
2022-10-16 22:56:51.859 I/System.out: }
2022-10-16 22:56:51.859 I/System.out: <<<<<
```